# SSIS config file at runtime

Tags: .net, ssis, etl, dts

I want to execute an SSIS package as a child from another SSIS package.  I have setup two configurations in the child package; one of them is a Parent Package Variable, and one is an XML Configuration File.  In my parent package, I need to make use of **both** configurations at the same time.

This is probably a newbie question, but the SSIS step 'Execute Package Task' doesn't allow you to point to a `dtsConfig` file.  I know the Parent Package Variable will work, but how do I get the child package to use the `dtsConfig` file in this scenario?  What if I want a few `dtsConfig` files and I want to pick between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont have to point the execute package task to the config file. When you run "pkg Parent" it will read its config file as you specified on the delevopment. When it calls the "pkg child", the child will read the variable from the parent and then will read its own config file which yo ucan set the same way you did on the parent

Comment: Thanks. So when I create a new `Configuration` from within BIDS, set to XML file, that is the one which is loaded automatically? So if I have several dtsConfig files in that directory, only the correct one will be loaded?

Comment: it will only load the config files you set on your projrct (by right clicking the applicationg and going to configurations). You can have more than one and it will load the configs based on the order you set

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify a configuration file with the `Execute Package Task`.

A possible solution would be to execute the package programatically and use the `ImportConfigurationFile` method on a package object to attach your XML configuration. You would execute this code in a `Script Task`.

[Example code on executing a package programatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136090.aspx)